# Why after put command in HDFS the new file seems to be empty?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

after several tries I figured out how to put a file from local sys to HDFS.
I'm able to see the added files trough HDFS GUI. But the file seems to be empty even though has some dimension.

Command that I used to put file in HDFS:

```
hadoop fs -put /input.txt /input.txt
```

Here view from HADOOP GUI
[image: hadoop-gui]

[image: empty file]

Even if I create other files, all of them have same dimension 340 B.
What's wrong with this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't think you are uploading what you think you are. You need to show us `cat /input.txt`

Comment: What? I didn't get it. Anyway these are the steps that I followed: 1)hdfs dfs -mkdir -p /user/input  2) hdfs dfs -put /input.txt /user/input 3)hdfs dfs -ls /user/input.

Comment: Those steps are correct. Your `/input.txt` file is simply empty (or literally has the text `[object Object]`, as the image shows). Please [edit] your question to show `cat /input.txt` rather than the Namenode UI